# Tabular ordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists, multiple-columns

I need to make an ordered list with tabular content that renders something like this:

```
1. Winner         00:00
2. Runner up      00:00
3. Looser         00:00
```

Now, I've managed to do this using the following HTML:

```html
<ol>
    <li><dl><dt>Winner</dt><dd>00:00</dd></dl></li>
    <li><dl><dt>Runner up</dt><dd>00:00</dd></dl></li>
    <li><dl><dt>Looser</dt><dd>00:00</dd></dl></li>
</ol>
```

and CSS:

```css
dt {
    display: inline-block;
    width:   5em;
}
dd {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

which renders correctly in the latest Chrome, Safari and Firefox. I don't know about IE.

However, it doesn't feel right. Are there a more semantic approach to solving this problem using HTML and CSS only?

Comment: what browser support is needed?

Comment: Chrome, Safari, FF, Opera and IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as CSS semantics, this is definitely not a good thing to do.  (for one thing I can't seem to get it to work in chrome).  Because this is tabular data, it should be placed in a table.  As for automatic incrementation, you could use the css count attribute:

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4AhgP/)

```
table{counter-reset:number;}

table tr td:first-child:before
{
    counter-increment:number;
    content:counter(number) ". ";
}
```

Comment: That would eliminate order as conveyed by HTML, you may as well just use a dl then.  If the order is relevant, the numbers belong in cells like the rest of the data.

Comment: @reisio The order is irrelevant per the example provided by the OP, which uses an ordered list...

Comment: *Order* -ed lists convey order.  As I said, if it's relevant you need to include *HTML* (not CSS) for it, and if not you don't need a table (since simple pairs are covered fine by a dl).

Comment: I had no idea about automatic numbering of table rows through CSS and have been searching myself blind on ordered lists. Thank you!

Comment: Again, you need to inlude the numbers in cells if they are relevant (if the order matters / is of significance), otherwise you can use a counter with a dl only.

Comment: @reisio that's true.  You could use a counter for anything, but considering this tabular data that needs to be displayed in a table like format, it's probably best to place it in a table.

Comment: No, a dl and a table with assumed headers and only two columns are semantically indistinguishable.

Comment: @reisio The solution that Joseph came up with is a three column table with the numbers in their very own cells.

Comment: No, what he came up with is a table with an empty cell starting each row, and CSS to make it look like there are numbers.  If you don't understand the difference, you don't understand HTML, which will cause you problems.

Comment: @reisio actually, the rendered content *is* within the first cell because it uses :after which occurs after the content but still within the element.  In any case this is all superfluous commentary.  **1)**  It's still tabular data (in content and the way it is displayed.  Note that using dl's will require fixed widths with display:inline-block). **2)**  The question was *semantics* and I gave the answer in terms of semantics.  **3)** The order is not important because the original scenario doesn't even call for it (it uses an ordered list).  I don't see why more discussion is necessary.

Comment: The *rendered* content is in the cells, but to a UA without CSS it doesn't exist at all; because CSS is not for content, it's for style. Ignoring the numbers it's fine as either a dl or a table, but a dl takes less markup. You don't seem to know what semantics are in this context. The order is only unimportant if the data isn't presented in some particular chronology/sequence. Ordered lists convey that the order matters, they are not style (CSS), they're meaning (HTML). It's not particularly necessary, but you should know this.

Comment: @reisio I disagree. The data presented is tabular data with multiple columns. Again, you have to understand that with the less markup you will also have to add in confusing style rules including the ever messy fixed width column.  Tables handle this sort of thing very nicely allowing the content to determine the dimensions. Furthermore, numbering that is irrelevant to the data (as in this case) *is* styling and *not* content and therefore belongs in CSS... not the HTML as you correctly pointed out.  I assume you downvoted me. That's fine but I do believe you are incorrect in doing so.

Comment: It's definitely table data with the numbers (note my own [unchanged] answer), but you aren't including the numbers, you're just telling CSS to show them. I don't see how you can say the order is irrelevant, as the OP clearly asked for ordered & has said nothing else on the matter. BUT again that's only part of it. There's simply no situation in which a bunch of empty cells for "holding" purely stylistic data is justified, ever. AND in the event the order truly doesn't matter, you can add the numbers with just CSS *more simply* by using a dl, which would in such an event be just as apt or more.

Comment: I may have chosen wrong terms when asking the question. I'll try to clarify. It IS an ordered list. But the only real data in the list is the text in the 2nd column and the times in the 3rd column. The 3rd column data is deciding the actual order. The numbers in the first column merely describes the item/row number to indicate rank, hence my initial use of `<ol>`. I was assuming that nesting `<dl>` inside `<ol>` for this job was bad practice (and definitely poor semantics) since it is not a list of lists of a term and it's definition - which is how the HTML in my question actually reads.

Comment: Rank matters in competition IME, and should therefore more than mere style.  Your initial markup was not wrong, but a table uses the exact same number of tags and is a little more straightforward (as you are only interpreting one element type set [a table] instead of two [ordered list, definition list]).  If you really see the numers as irrelevant (again), you could use *just* the dl and CSS for the numbers.

Comment: Allrighty - I've ended up with a 3 column table with the ranking numbers scripted into the first column cells as content. Thanks for all the inputs!

Answer (score 0):

The `table` element.